# Combine nested for loops in python

Tags: python, loops

Suppose I have a nested loop of the form:

```
for i in List1:
    for j in List2:
        DoSomething(i,j)
```

Can it be done as follows:

```
for i,j in combine(List1, List2):
    DoSomething(i,j)
```

Thanks in advance

So to clarify the combine function would do something as follows:

```
List1 = range(5)
List2 = range(5)
combine(List1, List2,)
>>> (0,0)
>>> (0,1)
>>> (0,2)
.
.
.
>>> (2,4)
>>> (3,0)
.
.
.
```

The itertools.product works perfectly

Comment: what is you actual problem you are trying to solve? Yes you can combine lists, but the nested loop works like a 2 dimensional array. How would like the combine function to behave? Please update your post to narrow your question.

Comment: I would say he wants to `DoSomething` in a nested-loop without explicitly nesting loops. IMO the question is not very verbose, but clear in this extent. And the perfect answer has already been given: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43498876/6525140

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`

```
import itertools
for i,j in itertools.product(List1, List2):
    DoSomething(i,j)
```